# Import modules while Userform is active

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to put all the buttons along a file in a more professional way using an userform. The files are shared to people and I'm using an export/import modules to avoid giving new copies everytime I change the code, but I'm stuck at trying to insert a button which will update the modules in the userform.

I have this code:

```
Private Sub Actualiza_Click()
    Unload Servicios
    On Error Resume Next
    ImportModules
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3)
    ImportModules
    On Error GoTo 0
    Servicios.Show
End Sub
```

But at the end everything is updated but the userform which is deleted.

The code to import is this one:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ImportModules()
    Dim wkbTarget As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim objFile As Scripting.File
    Dim szTargetWorkbook As String
    Dim szImportPath As String
    Dim szFileName As String
    Dim cmpComponents As VBIDE.VBComponents
'


    'Get the path to the folder with modules
    If FolderWithVBAProjectFiles = "Error" Then
        MsgBox "Import Folder not exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ''' NOTE: This workbook must be open in Excel.
    szTargetWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Set wkbTarget = Application.Workbooks(szTargetWorkbook)
    
    If wkbTarget.VBProject.Protection = 1 Then
    MsgBox "The VBA in this workbook is protected," & _
        "not possible to Import the code"
    Exit Sub
    End If

    ''' NOTE: Path where the code modules are located.
    szImportPath = FolderWithVBAProjectFiles & "\"
        
    Set objFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    If objFSO.GetFolder(szImportPath).Files.Count = 0 Then
       MsgBox "There are no files to import"
       Exit Sub
    End If

    'Delete all modules/Userforms from the ActiveWorkbook
    Call DeleteVBAModulesAndUserForms

    Set cmpComponents = wkbTarget.VBProject.VBComponents
    
    ''' Import all the code modules in the specified path
    ''' to the ActiveWorkbook.
    For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder(szImportPath).Files
        If objFile.Name Like "*Modulos*" Then GoTo Siguiente
        If (objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "cls") Or _
            (objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "frm") Or _
            (objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "bas") Then
            cmpComponents.Import objFile.Path
        End If
Siguiente:
    Next objFile
    
End Sub
```

The code works perfectly if used outside the userform, but not when the userform runs.

Comment: I am afraid that `DeleteVBAModulesAndUserForms` does exactly that if you did not specify what kind of module to be deleted. Please, edit your question and post also its code. Or your form must NOT be in the workbook where from all modules are (probably copied) and deleted. Assure your code to not work if `ThisWorkbook.name = ActiveWorkbook.Name`...

Comment: @FaneDuru thanks for your answer, but that's intended. I want all my modules, included the userform to be deleted and then to be copied from the folder with the new code. My problem comes when the userform is involved, then it won't be copied back from the folder.

Comment: But, if the code is run on the form to be deleted, how the code will run in a non existing object after its deletion...? If you would post `DeleteVBAModulesAndUserForms` code, as I suggested, we will find a way to skip deletion of that specific form...

Comment: That is the thing, it doesn't skip the deletion, it gets deleted but won't get copied back.

Comment: I am afraid that, without seeing the deletion code,  I cannot give any piece of advice... The fact is that the deletion code **must be adapted to skip the form in discussion**.

Comment: I've done something similar in the past but I had my code in `Workbook_Open` event. So everytime workbook is opened, it checks for the latest version and them imports it if needed

Comment: @FaneDuru the form gets updated aswell. Zac that could work but with a MsgBox asking if the user wants to update.

Comment: @Damian: the way i had it was to have the version number for each component embedded in it (i.e. module would have a constant declared with version number) and then i had the version for each component added in the file name. This way i could check if current version was different from the one in the folder. If it was, it updated the component. This way updates were done based on each component rather than updating all components